# How to calculate total physical memory used by processes forked from same parent?

Tags: linux, memory-management, nginx

We are using nginx for proxy service. We customized it a lot and it uses lots of memory.

On startup, nginx master uses 1.5GB memory and the master forks lots of workers. So each worker in the beginning uses 1.5GB memory inherited from master process. When handling requests a worker may modify these inherited memory and copy-on-write will be triggered so that more physical memory will be used. Also a worker may allocate memory on itself.

Our problem is how to calculate the total memory of these group of processes. The hard thing is lots of memory used by these processes use the same portion of physical memory, so we cannot simply add up the used memory of each process to get the total memory usage.

Comment: "each worker in the beginning uses 1.5GB memory inherited from master process". As you have mentioned copy-on-write you know that that 1.5GB is shared with the parent until it is written to. So it's not really using an extra 1.5GB of physical memory at the start as you seem to be implying. Just wanted to clarify that point.

Comment: To do what you want look at parsing `/proc/[pid]/smaps`. Read the [proc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, at beginning no extra physical memory is used because that 1.5GB is shared by the parent and all child processes. But with time goes on, the child process can modify part of these 1.5GB memory and it can also allocate additional memory on its own behalf. My question is how to know the total physical memory used by the parent and its child processes? Because we want to monitor the memory usage of each service, but summing up the memory of each process will give a huge number. e.g. if we have 16 workers, the total memory calculated by that way will be at least (16 + 1) * 1.5GB.

Comment: Like I said, parse `/proc/[pid]/smaps`.

Comment: You are right, @kaylum, the actually physical memory used by these processes can be calculated by parsing /proc/[pid]/smaps. Following script does it well: `for pid in $(pgrep nginx); do cat /proc/$pid/smaps; done | grep Pss | awk '{mem += $2} END {print mem, "kB"}'`  I have a reference about this Pss (http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/)

Comment: Good work. Suggest you post it as an answer to this question (it's ok to post an answer to your own question).

Answer (score 2):

The amortized memory used by a process can be calculated from the Pss. See http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/ for more info about Pss.

For the total memory used by a group of process, in this case the nginx master process and all slave processes, we can use following script to sum up all Pss of these processes:

```
for pid in $(pgrep nginx); do cat /proc/$pid/smaps; done | awk '/Pss/ {mem += $2} END {print mem, "kB"}'
```

Comment: You don't need `grep` and `awk`, just `awk '/Pss/{mem += $2} END {print mem, "kB"}'`

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, I updated it in the answer.